# Problem loading Windows

Tags: dual-boot, windows, bootloader

My Ubuntu shows the startup screen where I've to select the OS option, in it shows Windows 7 option too, but when I choose Windows 7, it doesn't load and shows back the same OS selection screen.

Both OS are installed on the same drive too.

Maybe during installation, I changed the address where the Windows 7 bootloader is located

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

There have been problems like this with Windows 7 and 8 for a while. Windows has all sorts of picky requirements when it comes to installing. I had a lot of problems like this in the past, and I think that maybe it had something to do with Windows wanting to be installed on the first partition of the disk. I can't remember exactly, though, because after  a lot of hassle, I just installed Windows on a separate HD.

Is your Windows on a separate partition of the same disk, or is it on a different disk?

If it's on a different disk, you are in luck. Just call up the boot menu when you turn on your PC and boot to that HD instead of the one with Ubuntu on it.